# Binding/Unbiding backbonejs events into RxJS

Tags: backbone.js, rxjs

I am trying RxJS with my backbone project. Currently I have backbone styled events in view such as

```
events:{
    "click .cross_10_10":"clearSearch",
    "keypress .searchUsers": "searchUsers"
}
```

Backbone handles binding/unbinding these events appropriately. How can I use `Rx.Observable.fromEvent`/`Rx.Observable.fromEventPattern` to bind these events which also gets unbind when view disappears.

[GitHub docs](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/gettingstarted/events.md) says RxJS supports hooks into backbone but could not find out how.

Current code

```
MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    constructor: function(container) {
      var html = $.trim($("script#tmpl_myview").html());
      this.el = $(_.template(html)({type:"random"}));
    },
    events:{
      "keypress .searchUsers": "searchUsers"
    },
    searchUsers: function() {
       var searchTerm = this.$(".searchUsers").val().trim();
       $.get("/searchUsers?q="+searchTerm)
       .then(_.bind(this.drawUsers, this));
    },
    drawUsers: function(users) {
       //render users in dom
    }
})
```

I want to user RxJS to throttle search queries. If it was just jquery, not backbone, I would do this.

```
var keyStream = Rx.Observable.fromEvent($(".searchUsers"), 'keypress').debounce(300)
.map(function(e){
    return $(".searchUsers").val();
}).distinctUntilChanged();
var respStream = keyStream.switchMap(function(searchTerm){
    return $.get("/searchUsers?q="+searchTerm);
});
respStream.subscribe(function(users){
//render
});
```

I want to combine both and use best of these.

Comment: That page says *"Natively, RxJS supports a number of libraries and hooks into them such as jQuery, ... and Backbone.js for using their event system"*. It says **"their event system"** which I believe means backbones built in event mechanism, not the event hash which deals with DOM events. Especially based on this [Github issue](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/issues/679)

Comment: They said *"what we found is that a lot of libraries had .on and .off methods where we could easily wrap around that."*. It's very unlikely they deal with backbone event hash. Maybe it'll be a good idea to raise an issue and clarify this in their GitHub. BTW, what are you trying to achieve by this?

Comment: I also read the same. I have some filter related checkboxes and search box. I want to take input from these, and fire search call to backend, get data and render it. when view disappears, those checkbox and keyboard input should get unbinded too.

Comment: Edit additional details into your question. Also, if possible, provide a [mcve].

Comment: @hridayesh I don't see any reason why you can't do that with normal events. The question is why you need RxJS for this?

Comment: In actual scenario there are many search types and filters out which I took one of them in example. Through RxJS i want to combine all of these to return one stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is the code for registering DOM events based on view's event hash:

```
 delegateEvents: function(events) {
  events || (events = _.result(this, 'events'));
  if (!events) return this;
  this.undelegateEvents();
  for (var key in events) {
    var method = events[key];
    if (!_.isFunction(method)) method = this[method];
    if (!method) continue;
    var match = key.match(delegateEventSplitter);
    this.delegate(match[1], match[2], _.bind(method, this));
  }
  return this;
},
delegate: function(eventName, selector, listener) {
  this.$el.on(eventName + '.delegateEvents' + this.cid, selector, listener);
  return this;
},
undelegateEvents: function() {
  if (this.$el) this.$el.off('.delegateEvents' + this.cid);
  return this;
},
```

`delegateEvents` is called while view is constructed and `undelegateEvents` is invoked internally by view's `remove`. You can override `delegateEvents` and `undelegateEvents` methods to add and remove your RxJS functionality for a specific view, or a base view that all your views extend from.